# PowerShell regex match multiline between delimiters

Tags: regex, powershell

For example I have a text:

```
Captain:
dynamic_captain : 1
elected_captain : Fri Mar 24 15:05:33 2023
id : 2377A74B-50DE-4C29-B79F-12A6853781B8
initialized_flag : 1
kvstore_maintenance_status : disabled
label : cbp-spl-sh03
mgmt_uri : https://cbp-spl-sh03.domain:8089
min_peers_joined_flag : 1
rolling_restart_flag : 0
service_ready_flag : 1
Members: 
cbp-spl-sh04
label : cbp-spl-sh04
last_conf_replication : Sat Mar 25 13:06:30 2023
mgmt_uri : https://cbp-spl-sh04.domain:8089
mgmt_uri_alias : https://172.28.56.119:8089
status : Up
cbp-spl-sh03
label : cbp-spl-sh03
mgmt_uri : https://cbp-spl-sh03.domin:8089
mgmt_uri_alias : https://172.28.56.118:8089
status : Up
cbp-spl-sh01
label : cbp-spl-sh01
last_conf_replication : Sat Mar 25 13:06:32 2023
mgmt_uri : https://cbp-spl-sh01.domain:8089
mgmt_uri_alias : https://172.28.56.100:8089
status : Up
cbp-spl-sh02
label : cbp-spl-sh02
last_conf_replication : Sat Mar 25 13:06:31 2023
mgmt_uri : https://cbp-spl-sh02.domain:8089
mgmt_uri_alias : h
```

I want to take each line between 'Captain:' and 'Members:' and transform it into a string array. Each line is an array element.
Which regex do I need to do it with?
I tried `Select-String '(?<=Captain:\n)(.|\n)*(?=\n\sMembers:)'` that works on regex101 but the output is empty.

Comment: The `\s` before `Members:` doesn't have a quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating string arrays, you could also convert this into 1 'Captain' Hashtable and a second 'Members' **array** of Hashtables.

Suppose you read the text like this into a single multiline string:

```
$text = Get-Content -Path 'X:\TheFile.txt' -Raw

# split on the line 'Members:' line to get two blocks of text
$blocks  = $text -split '(?m)^Members:\s*'

# the first textblock has the Captain data including the 'Captain:' line on top
$captain = $blocks[0] -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-StringData
# if you are using PowerShell version >= 7 you can do
# $_ -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'

# the second textblock has the members data without the 'Members:' line since we lost that in the split
$members = $blocks[1] -split '(?m)^[^:]+$' | ForEach-Object {
    # for PowerShell below version 7, you need to change the ':' delimiter into '='
    $_ -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData | Where-Object { $_.Count }
    # if you are using PowerShell version >= 7 you can do
    # $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':' | Where-Object { $_.Count }
}


# show the Captain data
$captain
```

```
Name                        Value
----                        -----
dynamic_captain             1
elected_captain             Fri Mar 24 15:05:33 2023
id                          2377A74B-50DE-4C29-B79F-12A6853781B8
initialized_flag            1
kvstore_maintenance_status  disabled
label                       cbp-spl-sh03
mgmt_uri                    https://cbp-spl-sh03.domain:8089
min_peers_joined_flag       1
rolling_restart_flag        0
service_ready_flag          1
```

```
# show the Members data (for clarity I'm adding a newline between the different Hashtables)
$members | ForEach-Object { $_; '' }
```

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                       
last_conf_replication          Sat Mar 25 13:06:30 2023                                                                                    
mgmt_uri                       https://cbp-spl-sh04.domain:8089                                                                            
status                         Up                                                                                                          
label                          cbp-spl-sh04                                                                                                
mgmt_uri_alias                 https://172.28.56.119:8089                                                                                  

status                         Up                                                                                                          
mgmt_uri                       https://cbp-spl-sh03.domin:8089                                                                             
label                          cbp-spl-sh03                                                                                                
mgmt_uri_alias                 https://172.28.56.118:8089                                                                                  

last_conf_replication          Sat Mar 25 13:06:32 2023                                                                                    
mgmt_uri                       https://cbp-spl-sh01.domain:8089                                                                            
status                         Up                                                                                                          
label                          cbp-spl-sh01                                                                                                
mgmt_uri_alias                 https://172.28.56.100:8089                                                                                  

last_conf_replication          Sat Mar 25 13:06:31 2023                                                                                    
mgmt_uri                       https://cbp-spl-sh02.domain:8089                                                                            
label                          cbp-spl-sh02                                                                                                
mgmt_uri_alias                 h
```

Comment: This is a new approach for me, but looks like what I want to see in the end. Thank you for answer, I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could omit the capture group, and match optional whitespace chars instead. You get the lines, you can split the match on a newline.

The inline modifier `(?s)` makes the dot match a newline, and `.*?` matches as few as possible characters.

```
$file = Get-Content -Raw file
$regex = '(?s)(?<=Captain:\n).*?(?=\n\s*Members:)'
Select-String $regex -input $file -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Matches.Value.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine)
    }
```

Result

```
dynamic_captain : 1
elected_captain : Fri Mar 24 15:05:33 2023
id : 2377A74B-50DE-4C29-B79F-12A6853781B8
initialized_flag : 1
kvstore_maintenance_status : disabled
label : cbp-spl-sh03
mgmt_uri : https://cbp-spl-sh03.domain:8089
min_peers_joined_flag : 1
rolling_restart_flag : 0
service_ready_flag : 1
```

Comment: Look pretty good, thank you. I will try it too.